# Understanding proof from Folland's Real Analysis 5.4

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

> if Y is complete, so is $L(X,Y)$.

Where $Y$ is complete normed vector space and $L(X,Y)$ is the space of linear maps between X and Y.

> Proof.  Let ${T_n }$ be a Cauchy sequence in $L(X, Y)$. If $x \in X$, then ${T_nx}$ is
> Cauchy in $Y$ because $\|T_n x - T_mx\| \leq \|T_n-T_m\|\|x\|$. Define $T:X\to Y$ by $Tx= \lim T_nx$ We leave it to the reader (Exercise 3) to verify that $T\in L(X,Y)$ and $\|T_n-T\|\to 0$.

There is a couple parts I am confused about, 1st:$$\|T_n x - T_mx\| \leq \|T_n-T_m\|\|x\|$$ I dont know how this inequality come to be?
The book defined operator norm as $\sup\{\|T(x)\|: \|x\|=1\}$.
Suppose $x\in X$ and $\|x\|=1$, then $\|Tx\|\leq \|T\|=\|T\|\|x\|$,

if $\|x\|\neq 1$, then $\|T\frac{1}{\|x\|}x\|=\frac{1}{\|x\|}\|Tx\|\leq \|T\|$, hence $\|Tx\|\leq \|x\|\|T\|$.

2nd: To finish the proof: Let $\lambda$ be a nonzero scalar, $x^\prime \in X$ such that $\{T_n(\lambda x^\prime+x)\}$, is cauchy in $Y$ by same logic, then define $T(\lambda x+x^\prime)=\lim T_n(\lambda x+x^\prime)$. Since $T_n$ is linear, we have  $T(\lambda x+x^\prime)=\lambda \lim T_n(x)+\lim T_n(x^\prime)=\lambda Tx+Tx^\prime$. Hence $T$ is linear, but I have trouble showing $\|T_n-T\|\to 0$. I think for this I have to show that for each $x\in X$ and $\|x\|=1$ we have $\|T_nx-Tx\|\to 0$, but then I don't really see whats there to be shown, since $x$ was arbitrary and $Tx$ was defined to be the limit of $T_nx$. It seems everything should follow directly after defining the limit. But I think I am missing something.

Comment: Use the definition of operator norm to show that for all $x\in X$, $\|T(x)\|\leq \|T\|\cdot\|x\|$. Work this out yourself (if $x=0$, obvious, otherwise, look at $T(x/\|x\|)$). And secondly, what did you try? As a last resort, search more carefully on this site; this is a very standard question. Anyway, this is the type of question which you MUST work out yourself, because it is a check of your understanding of definitions. Ask yourself: to prove $\|T_n-T\|\to 0$, what must you show? How can you use the definition of $T$ to help? What about the definition of operator norm? Does Cauchyness help?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thanks, you made me realized I've relied on the site a bit too often.